# How to record the response time in seconds between two button presses using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

im in need javascript code which will allow me to record response time in secs and output results (to a document e.g. task_times) for a number start and done buttons presses. I have an online test containing 10 simple html questions pages with a wrapper centering and displaying the questions with answering options.

A START button appears on a new page and the user clicking on it displays the question to be answered. When the user finishes, he presses DONE button to move a new start page for the next question. I would like to record these start and done button press time in seconds and write the difference between times to a text file (possibly with the name of the pages)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var start = Date.now();  
// do something
var end = Date.now();  
alert(end-start)
```

Do note though that if you don't want your users to tamper with this data, you'd better calculate time server-side.

Comment: Oleg, i have gone through the alert() method and it displays a pop up on the screen. Not too sure of the alert method. As much as possible i dont want the user to know the respoonse times but rather record them on a text document, which will also show all the response times between the relevant html start and done pages

Comment: Whatever you do with calculated data is up to you. It is only an example to show you results of calculations.

Comment: Oleg, can you please help me with an illustration in terms of coding with real buttons. I can then try it in jsfiddle. Sorry my javascript coding is a little obsolete, thus the reason for a lot of questioning

Answer (score 1):

since someone is still seeking an answer to this... You need to add event listeners to the 'start' and 'done' buttons and record the time using `new Date()`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qXe8s/1/)

```
function E(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
E('startButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var startTime = new Date();
    E('startButton').style.display = 'none';
    E('hidden').style.display = 'block';
    E('doneButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'Time taken (ms): '
            + (new Date() - startTime);
    });
});
```

To make a text file invisible to the user is not possible in client side javascript; you would need to submit the time to a server side script, which would record it and output the text file somewhere.